# Runningvalue with a sum(iif

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I was successful using Runningvalue here:

```
=FormatPercent(Runningvalue(Count(Fields!id.Value),Sum,"Tablix1")/ 
Count(Fields!id.Value,"Tablix1"),)
```

But when I try the next step to only capture the status "A"'s and determine the runningvalue

```
=Runningvalue(Sum(iif(Fields!status.Value = "A", 1, 0),Sum,"Tablix1")
/ Count(Fields!status.Value, "Tablix1"),)
```

I'm getting an error:  "Has an incorrect number of parameters for the function 'Runningvalue'.  I've tried this a number of ways and can't get it to work.

Comment: Your first parameter in RunnigValue is `Sum(iif(Fields!status.Value = "A", 1, 0)`, which means that particular part is missing a closing parenthesis, i.e. it should be `Sum(iif(Fields!status.Value = "A", 1, 0))`. If the expression works but doesn't give your desired result, please add a few rows of sample data with your required results.

Comment: Also, given you're already specifying the `Sum` aggregate in the `RunningValue` function, you probably don't even need the first `Sum`, i.e. something like `=Runningvalue(iif(Fields!status.Value = "A", 1, 0),Sum,"Tablix1")` should suffice.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  What I'm trying to do here is divide the total to get a running value in a percentage form.  I can get the first part of the code to run.  I can        =Runningvalue(iif(Fields!decision_status.Value = "A", 1,0),Sum,"Tablix1")     but when I try to add /count(Fields!id.Value, "Tablix1"),) I get an end of statement error

Comment: What about `=Runningvalue(iif(Fields!status.Value = "A", 1, 0),Sum,"Tablix1") / Count(Fields!status.Value, "Tablix1")` ? You don't need the last `,)`. As above, if this doesn't help it would be useful to update the question with some simple sample data that illustrates the issue.

Comment: That last one did it.  I dropped the ,) and got a result.  I really appreciate your help

Comment: OK, awesome! I've taken the liberty of adding that last one as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following expression run without error at least:

```
=Runningvalue(iif(Fields!status.Value = "A", 1, 0),Sum,"Tablix1")
  / Count(Fields!status.Value, "Tablix1")
```

There were a few issues with extra commas/parentheses and key words.